# Is is possible to detect the exact timings of Packet loss in between nodes of Vanet in OMNeT++?

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet, sumo

I have established the communication between the nodes in VANET and I have analyzed the vector file in order to detect packet loss. But how can I identify which packet lost at what particular time? I'm getting the total number of packets lost between each node but not getting the proper time constraints regarding packet drop. so how can I find this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can record an event log and parse either that or the simulation's standard output from the log view. Each individual packet loss event is logged.

Also if you are just interested in time stamps, check the packet drop statistics and enable the vector recording mode also on that statistic. By default it saves only the number of packets.

See: https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:declaring-statistics

Comment: Yeah I got it Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

Veins uses the `Decider80211p` to determine if a packet is decoded, not decoded, or collided. This is handled in the `packetOk` method.

Here you can collect any statistics to solve the problem. You can find hints for statistics in the post of Rudi